# How to filter specific field from child document in SOLR

Tags: solr, solrj

I have some nested data in the SOLR.

```
 {
    "name":["Abc"],
    "age":[30],
    "hobby":["singing"],
    "_childDocuments_":[
    {
      "college":["xyz"],
      "year":[2015],
      "id":"3752-22491",
      "3.c.m.c-id":["256939"],
      "2.c.m-id":["354291"],
      "path":["3.c.m.ci"]},
    {
      "subject":["history","science"],
      "marks-1":[75],
      "marks-2":[75],
      "id":"3752-802126",
      "2.c.m-id":["354291"],
      "path":["2.c.m"]}
    ]}
```

I am not to get only **marks-1** and **marks-2** from the solr. When I search than I find whole data as a response. I need help for fetching only these two fields.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: could you show your current query?

Comment: I am using this query (http://localhost:8983/solr/test/select?indent=on&highlight=true&start=0&rows=10&wt=json&hl=true&hl.method=unified&fl=*,[child parentFilter=path:1.c childFilter="path:*.c.*" limit=50]&q=name:Abc
)

Answer (score 0):

You couldn't do that with [ChildDocTransformer](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/transforming-result-documents.html#TransformingResultDocuments-_child_-ChildDocTransformerFactory), since it's purpose it to filter **which** child documents to show, not which **fields** of the child document to return.

Also, I'm pretty sure, that it will be just easier to filter out these fields in the client or during transformation of the response, since you will not get any performance improvement in limiting child document fields.

However, if you still want to do that via Solr query, you should use [subquery transformer](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/transforming-result-documents.html#TransformingResultDocuments-_subquery_) with something like this:

```
solr/collection_name/select?fl=id,title_t,stars:[subquery] //enter mode for subquery
&indent=on
&q=title_t:* // this is the general query, here, just selecting book
&stars.fl=stars_i // which fields from the child documents to return
&stars.q={!prefix f=id v=$row.id} // subquery that you need to adapt
```

I did this query on the collection of the books/reviews from [here](http://yonik.com/solr-nested-objects/) and it working just fine. However, you will need to adapt subquery. The problem here is, that you need to select only specific child documents, which correspond to the parent document. It could be some sort of *parent_id* or something else (I do not see this information in your data, so you will be need it).

Why do you need it? Otherwise, each of your parent document will contain underneath **ALL** child documents, that you will select with subquery. In my example, I'm using prefix query, since id of the child documents consists id of the parent document. E.g.

```
id:book1
```

and, child ids are:

```
id:book1_r1
```